# Best quotes practice when it doesn't matter?

Tags: bash

If I want to something like:

```
foo="bar baz"
foo='bar baz'
```

Is it best practice to use double-quotes or single-quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use double quotes unless I really need to use single quotes to stop variable interpolation or for other reasons.

Maybe this is part of my growing up with languages like Pascal, Fortran, and Basic which used double quotes and not single quotes. However, since most of the strings you use in BASH will do variable interpolation, you might as well get in the habit of using double quotes instead of thinking whether you need double quotes or single quotes in a statement. Also you're variable might be:

```
foo='Thank you!'
```

now, but when you modify it:

```
foo='Thank you, $name!'
```

You don't have to also remember to edit the quotes while, you're at it.

In the few situations where you actually need single quotes, you can easily mentally shift the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

It depends, as usual:

- Single quotes cannot contain other single quotes, and there's no way to escape them. For this reason they should only be used for 'simple' text.
- Double quotes support useful things like brace expansion (`echo "${USER} uses ${LANG#*.} encoding"`), but you can't include escape sequences in them. That means you generally won't be able to see the difference between for example `"[space][tab]"` and `"[tab]"` strings.
- Dollar-single quoted strings are much like double-quoted strings, but can contain control characters. My personal favorite for unit testing:

  ```
  $ echo -n $'--$`!*@\a\b\E\f\r\t\v\\\'"\360\240\202\211 \n' | uniname -bcepu
  glyph   name
  -      HYPHEN-MINUS
  -      HYPHEN-MINUS
  $      DOLLAR SIGN
  `      GRAVE ACCENT
  !      EXCLAMATION MARK
  *      ASTERISK
  @      COMMERCIAL AT
          BELL
          BACKSPACE
          ESCAPE
          FORM FEED (FF)
          CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
          CHARACTER TABULATION
          LINE TABULATION
  \      REVERSE SOLIDUS
  '      APOSTROPHE
  "      QUOTATION MARK
        Unknown character in range CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
          SPACE
          LINE FEED (LF)
  ```

If you want to know if you should use `$'` quoting or not for a variable, try sending it to `printf %q`:

```
$ var=foo
$ printf %q "$var"
foo
$ var="foo
> bar"
$ printf %q "$var"
$'foo\nbar'
```

Answer (score 1):

When it doesn't matter, it doesn't matter. Consistency is good though, so choose which one you like and use it consistently within your own code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a microefficiency argument in favor of single quotes, as the shell does not have to examine the quote to see if anything needs to be interpolated.

In Perl, for example, using single quotes for any literal string is sometimes considered a [best practice](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aValuesAndExpressions%3a%3aProhibitInterpolationOfLiterals).